# javascript onclick code change

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

got this code for a stylesheet changer

i am wanting to change it so it works in my bootstrap drop down button. Current code is below

```
<form id="switchform">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="none" onClick="chooseStyle(this.value, 60)">Default style<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="blue-theme" onClick="chooseStyle(this.value, 60)">Blue Theme<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="brown-theme" onClick="chooseStyle(this.value, 60)">Brown Theme
</form>
```

i want to add it to my bootstrap dropdown button. The current code is below

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mention your javaScript function 'chooseStyle'

Comment: Please put your code as said by Manoj

Comment: im using this code from dynamic drive. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm full source there

Comment: you could change the innerHTML property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<!-- demo code -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Theme Selection</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="chooseStyle('none', 60);return false">None</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="chooseStyle('blue-theme', 60); return false">Blue Theme</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="chooseStyle('brown-theme', 60); return false">Brown Theme</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```